# Win32Exception - error creating window handle?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox, focus

Can you explain why this happens? Here are steps to reproduce the exception:

1. Drag-n-drop a TextBox on a form. Add any other focusable control such as a button on the form.
2. Add 2 event handlers for that TextBox as follow:

   ```
   private void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e){
     ((TextBox)sender).HideSelection = false; //<-- exception highlighted at here.
   }

   private void textBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e){
     ((TextBox)sender).HideSelection = true;
   }
   ```
3. Run the form and first click on the textBox, then click on the button then click on the textBox again, and the exception will throw: "Win32Exception - error creating window handle".

The code is simply to make the HideSelection change accordingly when the textBox gets focused and loses focus.

## UPDATE

I don't know why is so volatile, I created another project and now the problem is different, there is no exception but an indefinite loop which makes the textbox flicker, the form doesn't seem to responsive, the CPU usage is consumed up to about 17-20%. The last demo is still opened and that demo still has the `Win32Exception` thrown. Not a clue at all. Now the code of the two projects are the same but the problems are different.

Comment: Are using a 3rd party textbox control with GotFocus and LostFocus events?

Comment: @Jeremy Thopmson These events do exist for the TextBox control, just are not available in the designer ;-)

Comment: @King King, the `TextBox` is redrawn multiple times before the form is shown. That is the first thing that I addressed when trying to diagnose your problem - I set a bool flag inside the `Form_Shown()` event handler and then used it to prevent the infinite loop on startup (by wrapping your code in it).  After getting past the infinite loop on startup, I then tried to solve your problem, but JeffRSon beat me to it!

Comment: @EtherealMonkey thanks, I hate debugging any thing related to Paint, Redrawn, Enter, Leave, GotFocus, LostFocus... all that stuff can make the execution jump randomly and sometimes repeatedly -->  baffled :)

Comment: @KingKing: Maybe in your first project the debugger is configured to show any System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception as soon as it is thrown while it isn't (yet) in the new project.

Comment: @JeffRSon I didn't touch any configuration, all the configuration is by default. I'll try to configure out or at least make them produce the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Compare in VS Debug/Exceptions

Comment: @JeffRSon I have checked, both the project have the same System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are a couple of things to note.

First of all, `HideSelection` doesn't hide or unhide the selection. It specifies, whether the selection will be hidden (or not) when the control loses focus. So it's pointless to change it when the `TextBox` becomes focus'ed.

What you're doing in `LostFocus` is default, btw. Why there is an exception in `GotFocus` is burried within Windows API, I guess. Maybe some undefined state when `HideSelection` checks inside a focus changed event whether the TextBox has focus or not or tries to hide the selection which is not shown.
Edit: It's not the Windows API on the first hand, but the framework. It tries to "recreate the handle" in the setter of HideSelection *if it is changed* (don't know why yet - would have to analyse sources) and seems to fail (don't know why either).
Edit2: Finally there's some problem in Win32 DestroyWindow - which leads to skipping the creation of the new window. Maybe because the old one is "in use" in the focus change events?

Interestingly, as soon as the exception occurs (for me), the `LostFocus` event is fired, immediately followed by `GotFocus` which throws another exception a.s.o. thus blocking the GUI. Both assignments to `HideSelection` throw the exception.

Also, when you click the `TextBox`, any selection is deselected automatically. This, however, is not the *reason* for the problem, because the exception is thrown if you change focus by pressing Tab (whose normal behaviour is to restore focus). But it may be related (state problems).

If you actually want to restore the selection, you could do it like this:

```
int selStart;
int selLen;
void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selStart = textBox1.SelectionStart;
    selLen = textBox1.SelectionLength;
}
void textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
       textBox1.SelectionStart = selStart;
       textBox1.SelectionLength = selLen;
    }));
}
```

Comment: Arrrggg, I can't get any rep on here... Always someone way quicker than me.  Congratulations, that's you today ;-)!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice the actual meaning of HideSelection :)

Answer (score 2):

I repro this crash.  You can easily see it going wrong by setting breakpoints on your event handlers, note how they fire over and over again before your program bombs.  The explanation is a bit long winded, I'll give the short version first.  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx) for the LostFocus event gives stern warnings, both a Note and a Caution, pointing out that this is a low-level event that is dangerous.  These events are also hidden in the Properties window for that reason.  Fix your problem by using the Enter and Leave event instead.

The long version: the TextBox.HideSelection property is rather special.  It is related to the way *some* properties on native Windows controls are specified.  These controls are created with the [CreateWindowEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) winapi function, it takes a dwExStyle and dwStyle argument, flags that specify style options for the window.  The HideSelection property is such a style flag, ES_NOHIDESEL.

That presents a problem when you want to *change* the property.  Difficult because it can only be specified when the native control is created.  Winforms does something pretty heroic to deal with that limitation, it destroys the native control and re-creates it.

That can have pretty interesting side effects, to put it mildly.  Most are not observable, but you do for example see the window on the screen getting destroyed and recreated.  That's why it flickers.  The core problem with your code is, inevitably, because the native window is getting destroyed it also loses the focus.  So the LostFocus event immediately fires, right after you got the GotFocus event.  Which does something unfortunate, it *again* changes the HideSelection property.  Which forces Winforms to recreate the native control again.

This repeats over and over again when your GotFocus event handler yet again runs for the new native control.  This does eventually end when Windows puts a stop to it and doesn't allow any more native windows to be created, it pulls the plug at 10,000 controls after a while.  Which generates the "Error creating window handle" exception.

The Enter and Leave events should always be used for focusing events, they only fire if the user actually moved the focus, and don't fire when it happened because of other reasons, like this one.  Also notable is that there's no point at all in changing the HideSelection property like you do, the property only has an affect when TextBox doesn't have the focus.  The selection is never hidden when it has the focus.  So the proper fix here is remove these event handlers and simply set the HideSelection property to True in the Properties window.  The default value.

Comment: Wow Thanks, your explanation helps me a lot, in fact I didn't notice the actual meaning of HideSelection before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cant reproduce this works for me:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).HideSelection = false;
}

private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).HideSelection = true;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I've tried a new project which has only 2 controls: the textbox and a button. And it even couldn't run normally. The textbox is flickered repeatedly , there seems to be some indefinite loop here, the CPU usage is consumed about 17%. The last demo was created when I have about 6 controls on the form.